# How to fill a large Gaussian with N smaller Gaussians

Tags: statistics, sampling

Lets say I have a multivariate Gaussian.  I'd like to "pack" that Gaussian full of smaller Gaussians.  Intuitively, it seems like I would just sample N points from the original MV Gaussian for the means, and then set each of their covariance to 1/N of the original covariance.  Is there a better/more formal way to accomplish what I'd like to do? I've attached an image of what I'm trying to get at, what is hard to show is that the density of the samples follows the original Gaussian distribution.

Thanks

[Here is an image of what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTn8P.png)

Comment: If you know the means and covariances, why would a finite sample help?  And could you give a univariate example as to what you mean by "packing" ?

Comment: I've added a picture for you.  I start with a Gaussian which is a very naive guess of where the solution to my problem may lie.  I'd like to sample the Gaussian and see which of the samples best represent measurements I am observing.  If the measurements happen to be very precise, I have to have many samples in order to "hit" the measurement.  I'd like to coarsely sample the Gaussian, but give each sample some "fatness".  Then, find the set of smaller Gaussians that adequately represent my measurement, and then recurse down until I am able to locate the source of my measurement.

Comment: Thanks.  What you show seems more like packing ellipses into a larger ellipse.  (You should be able to include the image right in the question.)

Comment: Yeah, apparently I don't have enough points to embed an image.  And for my problem, I can choose N arbitrarily, I am just trying to figure out what the "correct" variance would be for each sample given a chosen N.

Comment: There's literature out there about packing ellipses into other geometrical shapes.  For example:  https://www.researchgate.net/publication/320758872_Optimal_Packing_of_General_Ellipses_in_a_Circle.

Comment: thanks for the information, I'll take a look over that paper.